# buildr from svn repository

Tags: ruby, svn, continuous-integration, jruby, buildr

I would to run buildr on my svn repository - to build the files from \src\main\java in the subversion repository with username and password and save it to anther location on my disc.

How can I do it?

Comment: Are cron jobs available?

Comment: I mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: of course it could be done via cron if i knew how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand your question correctly, you are trying to setup a contiuous build system. checking out source code is the responsibility of your CI system. it would poll your svn, git or whatever cvs you use for changes and then build it on the configuration you provide.

a free build-server is jenkins (aka hudson). if you want a hosted solution you can go for travis-ci (it's free). or something expensive like atlassian bamboo.

Comment: Isn't it something that in buildr code should do? when I wrote the code in ANT, ant was in charge of checking out the code from svn and building the enviornment isn't it?

Comment: as i said, the ci system usually does it by polling your scm for changes. that is, because you would normally have buildr as a dependeny of your project and the ci system does not need to know about it. regardless of all this, just shell and execute svn commands directly, there is no need to have sonething special in buildr.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write an Ruby build script - that when you execute will:

1. Checkout the source
2. do the 'buildr'
3. Commit the built file(s)

http://www.markdeepwell.com/2010/06/ruby-subversion-bindings/
http://blog.carlossanchez.eu/2009/08/18/using-subversion-ruby-bindings/

Comment: I want to use buildr and not ant

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is run external svn commands

```
task :checkout do
    system 'svn checkout ..'
end
```